# How to partial fill the rectangle within canvas in xaml

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have some coordinates position on which I have to show the clickable button. SO inside button i created rectangle and everything is working as expected but now I have to show partially filled rectangle inside somewhat like rectangle bottom border.
Below is the code :

```
<StackPanel>
                <Button Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" 
                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.EventTriggerCommand, ElementName=XYZCOORD}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Users_Auth_Info}" Opacity="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding x}" Y="{Binding y}"/>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" Height="{Binding Thickness_param}" BorderThickness="8">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding x}" Y="{Binding y}"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>
```

Right now I'm showing transparent rectangle with border but border is not something i want.Please advise.

Comment: The XAML you posted isn't very helpful. It has bindings to things not declared in the example. And your title says you want to fill a Rectangle that's in a Canvas, but the XAML shows a StackPanel container instead. Finally, if you don't want a Border, then why not just remove the Border element from the XAML?

Comment: Its just an alternate which i have used I'm showing a transparent rectangle and below that a border but ideally what i need is rectangle filled upto the percent   we'll provide from the backend.

Comment: Are you saying that you've pushed the button to where you want it to be, but now you want to have a colored rectangle *inside* the button? If so, remove the `Button.Template` completely and instead just add a rectangle as the `Content`, either with Button.Content or as a direct child (`<Button><Rectangle/></Button>`). Also, you can remove the border by setting the button's `BorderThickness` to 0.

Comment: Finally figured it out. thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use button instead of border and inside that button use a rectangle. Attached the code

```
 <StackPanel>
                <Button Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" 
                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.EventTriggerCommand, ElementName=XYZCOORD}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Users_Auth_Info_Color}" Opacity="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding x}" Y="{Binding y}"/>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>

                <Button Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding Thickness_param}" 
                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.EventTriggerCommand, ElementName=XYZCOORD}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Users_Auth_Info_Color}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding x}" Y="{Binding y}"/>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
```